# Changing metadata when uploading file to s3 with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, bots

I have an html file that I am uploading to s3 using python. For some reason, s3 adds a system defined metadata saying that the file Content-Type is "binary/octet-stream":
[image]

I need to change this value to "text/html". I can do it manually, but I want it to be done automatically when I upload the file.
I tried the following code:

```
metadata = {
    "Content-Type": "text/html"
}
s3_file_key = str(Path("index.html"))
local_file_path = Path("~", "index.html").expanduser()
s3 = session.resource("s3")
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
with open(local_file_path, READ_BINARY) as local_file:
    bucket.put_object(Key=s3_file_key, Body=local_file, Metadata=metadata)
```

but the result was that the file had 2 metadata keys:

[image]

I couldn't find any documentation about how to change a system defined metadata.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Use *MetadataDirective* parameter:

```
bucket.put_object(Key=s3_file_key, Body=local_file, Metadata=metadata, MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```

**MetadataDirective** -- Specifies whether the metadata is copied from the source object or replaced with metadata provided in the request ('COPY' | 'REPLACE').

[S3 - Boto3 Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html)

Answer (score 1):

I was also having a similar problem and I found out you need to use the *ContentType* parameter for the `put_object` function.

```
bucket.put_object(Key=s3_file_key, Body=local_file, ContentType='text/html')
```